# how to run once a bunch of generated scripts with exception handling?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, error-handling

Before I restore a database, I need to save the contents of a table called `dbo.ref_systemSettings` if it exists.

So I created a script that calls a procedure that will save the contents of this table in a DBA database, **for all databases where this table exists**.

That is working fine, but I would like to automate this process, avoiding the copy and paste - see below.

How it works:
When I run the following script I get a bunch of scripts to be executed:

```
--============================================================================
-- to save the table dbo.ref_systemSettings in all the databases where it exists
-- just run the generated script below at Radhe
--============================================================================
SELECT name, Radhe='exec sp_save ' + '''' 
     + name + '.dbo.ref_systemSettings' + ''''
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(name+'.dbo.ref_systemSettings') IS NOT NULL
```

the query above produce the below:
[image]

which I copy and paste, in order to run:

```
exec sp_save 'my_db_01.dbo.ref_systemSettings'
exec sp_save 'my_db_02.dbo.ref_systemSettings'
exec sp_save 'my_db_03.dbo.ref_systemSettings'
exec sp_save 'my_db_04.dbo.ref_systemSettings'
```

when I run the whole of the query above, all my tables are saved into the DBA database. This is currently working fine.

**Question:**

I would like to eliminate the `copy and paste`.
what could be an effective way to run these scripts, while taking into consideration `exception handling`, lets say... there is no more space in the DBA database and the table cannot be saved... or any other expection??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result should be stored in a variable and should execute that  SQL.
It's called dynamic SQL.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

```
      BEGIN TRY

       DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
        SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql ,'')+'exec sp_save ' + '''' 
             + name + '.dbo.ref_systemSettings' + ''''+';'
        FROM sys.databases
        WHERE OBJECT_ID(name+'.dbo.ref_systemSettings') IS NOT NULL

        EXEC (@sql)

       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH

           DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
           DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
           DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

          SELECT   
             @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
             @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
             @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

          -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error  
          -- information about the original error that caused  
          -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.  
          RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
                     @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
                     @ErrorState -- State.  
                    ); 

       END CATCH
```

Comment: @marcellomiorelli, I used COALESCE method for string concatenation, hope it's not a big result set, if it is or you need an ordered execution; let's say you want to execute the sp in a particular order use XML method for string concatenation with an order by cluase defined

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cursor and execute each row at a time:

```
DECLARE @qstr varchar(1000)
DECLARE cur_query CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR   
    SELECT Radhe='sp_save ' + '''' 
    + name + '.dbo.ref_systemSettings' + ''''
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE OBJECT_ID(name+'.dbo.ref_systemSettings') IS NOT NULL

OPEN cur_query  
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_query INTO @qstr  

IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0   
    PRINT 'Nothing'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT @qstr
    exec (@qstr)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_query INTO @qstr
END  

CLOSE cur_query  
DEALLOCATE cur_query
```